# Логический тип boolean

Tags: java

Начал изучать java и все никак не могу понять зачем нужен boolean, было приведено много примеров, но это понятие до меня не доходит, кто нибудь обьясните пожалуйста доступно и с пониманием

[вот скрин примера из книги Шилдта о джаве](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58qo2.jpg)

Comment: Что конкретно вам непонятно в этой теме? Что именно нужно пояснить подробно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boolean может быть равен true или false (думаю вы это знаете).
Переменные этого типа обычно хранят значения какого-либо высказывания. К примеру:

```
A - луна квадратная = false
B - Кнопка нажата
С - Окно открыто
D - Провод подсоединен
```

Высказывание A = false (по понятным причинам), следовательно, это константа, обозначающая состояние Луны (она НЕ квадратная).
B, C, D - не константы и мы можем брать и задавать значения, а для А - только брать значение.

```
C = B И C
```

Мы откроем окно, если нажмем кнопку (B) и подсоединим провода (D)

**Вывод:** Boolean переменные выполняют роль [флагов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)), индикаторов состояний.

---

В вашем примере boolean found - это флаг того, что значение найдено.

```
if (found) // Сравнение found с константой true. Эквивалентно found == true
    Sysem.out.println("Нашли!");
```

Работает так:

```
Значение найдено?
  Да! -Печатаем на экран
  Нет, значит идем дальше.
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Значение boolean это правда/ложь. До цикла переменная инициализируется в false, затем в цикле если соблюдается условие - значение меняется на true. Если искомого не было в массиве, т.е. условие ни разу не соблюдалось - то так и останется false.

Почитай что нибудь про алгоритмы для начинающих. Даже если статья не на Java будет, у всех тип boolean работает одинаково.

Comment: Спасибо большое, благодаря вам я теперь понемногу начал понимать этот тип

Comment: @ДДД Проплюсуйте понятные и полезные ответы, и отметьте лучший. Если что-то еще не понятно - спрашивайте.

Answer (score 0):

Тип `boolean` появился из математической логики, основоположником которой был Джордж Буль. В программировании он нужен для работы операторов ветвления.

В "новых" языках программирования булевский тип был введен для возврата результатов логических операций. Этот тип может принимать только два значения `true` и `false` и не может приводиться к другим типам данных.

Разграничение арифметических и логических операций понадобилось для защиты от синтаксических ошибок программного кода. К примеру в языке C результатом логических операций будет целый тип, который будет непросто от других целочисленных переменных. При этом велика возможность перепутать оператор сравнения с оператором присваивания, или присвоить результату логического выражения какое-нибудь число, типа 42.

Запись такой операции не вызовет ошибки компиляции, но будет грубой ошибкой в коде и скорее всего приведет к поломке программы.